# Why can't you add reasoning when deleting your own answer and does editing it make it look like a new answer?

Tags: discussion, edits, deleted-answers

I answered one question and thought I made myself clear, however, someone commented I was confusing the issue even more. Since sometimes I can't express myself properly even in my native language (not talking about English) and it was about 4 in the morning I didn't think I was able to edit the answer properly and decided to delete it in order not to confuse anyone who stumbles upon the answer and can't read my mind. As I woke up, I searched back to it, reread it and I had to admit the commentator was right and it was really unclear what I wrote.

There was one thing that I found a bit confusing to me - when deleting the answer, there was just a question if I am sure and want to delete it. I was half-expecting something like *edit summary* where you can optionally write your reason why you decided that way, since [there is a lot of people who can see them even after deleting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126348/are-my-deleted-answers-visible-to-others). If the deleted answer would completely disappear, it wouldn't matter, but because it doesn't I find it useful to have the option to include your "deleting summary" to people who can see it.

Is there any reasoning behind why you can't add your reason when deleting your own answer (eg "I understood the question wrongly and answered something different", "My answer has too low quality", ...), or is it just that no one thought about this before, or that no one actually cares why you decide that way? I feel it can be a good way to express that you really thought about your answer and other people comments to it. Now deleting your own answer seems like "someone downvoted me, so I delete it".

I have also a second question which may be relevant to the backstory - if I decide to edit and revise my own deleted post (making sure I have it right now), does it act like it's a completely new answer (with possibly seeing the edits), or the comments and score stays there? If it stays that way (eg with the comment about how it's confusing), is it better to leave it deleted and add a new answer, since the comment is (hopefully) irrelevant to the new version? (not that I want to do it in the post that made me think about this, I am just generally curious and would like to know it in case it happens)

I tried searching for both my questions, but I didn't find anything that would answer them. I am sorry if they are obvious for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I must admin that I sometimes wonder why someone deleted their answer, when I stumble upon a deleted one. You shouldn't really bother though. You would only be giving a delete reason for the peace of mind of a reader such as me, or maybe for yourself when you find the answer again after a while.

If you do care, you can always leave a comment with your reason before deleting, or edit the answer to include the reason before or after deleting.

And if you undelete an answer, the comments and history remain on that answer.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. So, if I would like to post a completely different answer instead the one I screwed up, is it better to leave it deleted and create a new one, since the comments and / or score have nothing to do with what would be in the new version, or is it better to revise it and write a comment that I screwed it up and changed my answer and maybe some of the voters and commentators would change their mind about it?

Comment: I prefer to [edit after deletion](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Pt8TC.png "example"), and try to always do so, exactly for the reasons you explained - to let 10K and diamond readers see my reasons

Comment: @gnat that sounds like a solution to it. Do you have also any advice for the situation I described in the comment above?

Comment: @Adalee for particular case you ask about, I would likely add on top of the deleted answer something like "**Deletion explanation:** I understood the question wrongly and answered something different". In cases when I find comments (like one you mention) particularly helpful, I tend to additionally state something like "(special thanks to commenter for helping me realise this)"

Comment: As for the edit or post a new answer: I can't find any policy on that. If your old answers got not that many votes or comments, just edit and undelete.

Comment: @CodeCaster me neither, that's why I am asking if there is any unwritten rule for that, or if I am just unable to search :) thanks for your opinion.

Comment: @gnat I meant my question int the first comment on this post - if I would like to rewrite the answer since the original one was completely wrong, is it better to post it as new answer, or edit and undelete the original one, since the comments and score of the original answer will stay there and it will have nothing to do with the new version?

Comment: @Adalee for rewrite like you describe, I tend to edit+undelete in cases when my answer was visible only briefly and didn't gain many comments / votes. If it has gotten a solid "history", I rather prefer delete (with an explanation like mentioned above) + new answer

Comment: Thank you both for your opinions and experience!